# Pc shutdown when headphones jack is plugged

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, headphones, jack

On a PC with dual boot Ubuntu Mate (16.04) - Windows 10 when the heaphones jack is plugged in the PC shutdown within 2 seconds, but only if it's using battery and not AC power. This only happens on Ubuntu, while on Windows everything works just fine.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

From the answer mentioned in [16.04 - Laptop cuts power when headphones were plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867849/16-04-laptop-cuts-power-when-headphones-were-plugged-in)  You have to disable the power saving mode for Intel HD sounds

1) 
`sudo gedit /etc/default/tlp`

2) Then replace
`SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=1`
with
`SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=0`

3) `sudo service tlp restart`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm now using Ubuntu GNOME for some months and the problem never appeared on this distro...

Comment: I was using Ubuntu Mate and it still had the issue, anyhow glad it worked out :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you need to disable power saving mode on Intel HD Audio.

```
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave
```

In the file:

```
#INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=${INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE:-true}
INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=false
```