# 16.04 - Laptop cuts power when headphones were plugged in

Tags: 16.04, sound, shutdown, audio-jack

Acer Aspire E5-574G running Xubuntu 16.04.
When headphones were plugged in, laptop immediately cuts off power.
When I turn it back on again. It cuts power again after login. (When headphone is still plugged in.)
What gives?

edit: Sorry about that, solved the problem myself. The issue is power saving mode on intel hd audio (TLP). Disable it and it's good to go. Hope it helps who ever experiencing this problem!

Comment: You could add you edit as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is power saving mode on intel hd audio in the [TLP configuration](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html#audio). Disable it and it's good to go. Hope it helps who ever experiencing this problem!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/tlp
```

Replace

```
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=1
```

with

```
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=0
```

Save the file and exit, then run

```
sudo service tlp restart
```