# Laptop shuts down when headphones jack plugs in

Tags: shutdown, laptop, hda-intel

My Acer Extensa 2520G with Ubuntu 22.04 turns off on plugging headphones jack

I've tryed [both this solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834576/pc-shutdown-when-headphones-jack-is-plugged) and it's not helps in my case

My system hasn't TLP so i've install it and add to empty file `/etc/default/tlp` `SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=0`

My system has `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d` folder but hasn't `intel-audio-powersave` in it, only `95hdparm-apm` so i create `intel-audio-powersave` and add `INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=false` it's not helps too

This is my logs:

```csharp
Nov  3 10:12:54 AcerX /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1221]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   76.42  1366 1434 1479 1592  768 772 779 800 -hsync -vsync (48.0 kHz eP)
Nov  3 10:12:54 AcerX gnome-shell[1771]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Nov  3 10:12:54 AcerX gnome-shell[1771]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Nov  3 10:12:54 AcerX gnome-shell[1771]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Nov  3 10:12:54 AcerX gnome-shell[1771]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Nov  3 10:12:54 AcerX gnome-shell[1771]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Nov  3 10:12:54 AcerX gnome-shell[1771]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Nov  3 10:12:54 AcerX gnome-shell[1771]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Nov  3 10:12:54 AcerX gnome-shell[1771]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Nov  3 10:12:54 AcerX gnome-shell[1771]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Nov  3 10:12:55 AcerX gnome-shell[1771]: GNOME Shell started at Fri Nov 03 2023 10:12:49 GMT+0300 (MSK)
Nov  3 10:12:55 AcerX gnome-shell[1771]: Registering session with GDM
Nov  3 10:12:55 AcerX dbus-daemon[1224]: [session uid=1000 pid=1224] Activating service name='org.gnome.ArchiveManager1' requested by ':1.86' (uid=1000 pid=2196 comm="gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rasters" label="unconfined")
Nov  3 10:12:56 AcerX dbus-daemon[1224]: [session uid=1000 pid=1224] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ArchiveManager1'
Nov  3 10:12:56 AcerX dbus-daemon[1224]: [session uid=1000 pid=1224] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' unit='gvfs-metadata.service' requested by ':1.86' (uid=1000 pid=2196 comm="gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rasters" label="unconfined")
Nov  3 10:12:56 AcerX systemd[1037]: Starting Virtual filesystem metadata service...
Nov  3 10:12:56 AcerX dbus-daemon[1224]: [session uid=1000 pid=1224] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata'
Nov  3 10:12:56 AcerX systemd[1037]: Started Virtual filesystem metadata service.
Nov  3 10:12:56 AcerX gnome-shell[1771]: DING: Detected async api for thumbnails
Nov  3 10:12:56 AcerX gnome-shell[1771]: DING: GNOME nautilus 42.6
Nov  3 10:12:57 AcerX dbus-daemon[1224]: [session uid=1000 pid=1224] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files'
Nov  3 10:12:57 AcerX systemd[1037]: Started Tracker file system data miner.
Nov  3 10:12:57 AcerX systemd[1037]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Nov  3 10:12:57 AcerX systemd[1037]: Reached target Main User Target.
Nov  3 10:12:57 AcerX systemd[1037]: Startup finished in 45.946s.
Nov  3 10:13:04 AcerX nautilus[1906]: Could not delete '.meta.isrunning': No such file or directory
Nov  3 10:13:05 AcerX ubuntu-report[1159]: level=error msg="data were not delivered successfully to metrics server, retrying in 60s"
Nov  3 10:13:21 AcerX systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov  3 10:13:22 AcerX systemd[1]: systemd-localed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov  3 10:13:50 AcerX geoclue[1890]: Service not used for 60 seconds. Shutting down..
Nov  3 10:13:50 AcerX systemd[1]: geoclue.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov  3 10:13:51 AcerX systemd[1037]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Nov  3 10:13:51 AcerX systemd[1037]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Nov  3 10:13:55 AcerX ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[1771]: unable to update icon for software-update-available
Nov  3 10:13:55 AcerX ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[1771]: unable to update icon for livepatch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I’ve install user interface for TLP and modify configuration throw it and it works

Comment: Interesting that the driver is still causing trouble. I have added your symptom to the FAQ: https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/operation.html#spontaneous-shutdown-on-battery

Comment: also discovered the following behavior: if jack plugged in before system startup it crashes on turning on, but if system is loaded and i plug in jack it works normally

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "crashes on turning on"? At the moment when you power on the laptop there is no operating system that can crash, you're still in UEFI/BIOS. Do you mean the system crashes after booting the operating system?

Comment: You also contradict your original statement: "Laptop shuts down when headphones jack plugs in".

Comment: This is the behavior after a configuration change. Before this, the laptop turned off when trying to start the operating system with headphones connected / turned off when headphones were connected while the system is running. After changing configuration, it's shutdown when trying to start the operating system with a headphone connected